# OpenCV Optical flow Sample Code Error

Tags: python, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("slow.avi")
while not cap.isOpened():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("slow.avi")
    cv2.waitKey(1000)
    print "Wait for the header"

# params for ShiTomasi corner detection
feature_params = dict( maxCorners = 100,
                       qualityLevel = 0.3,
                       minDistance = 7,
                       blockSize = 7 )

# Parameters for lucas kanade optical flow
lk_params = dict( winSize  = (15,15),
                  maxLevel = 2,
                  criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03))

# Create some random colors
color = np.random.randint(0,255,(100,3))

# Take first frame and find corners in it
ret, old_frame = cap.read()
old_gray = cv2.cvtColor(old_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
p0 = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(old_gray, mask = None, **feature_params)

#print old_frame

# Create a mask image for drawing purposes
mask = np.zeros_like(old_frame)

while(1):    
    ret,frame = cap.read()

    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # calculate optical flow
    p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, p0, None, **lk_params)

    # Select good points
    good_new = p1[st==1]
    good_old = p0[st==1]

    # draw the tracks
    for i,(new,old) in enumerate(zip(good_new,good_old)):
        a,b = new.ravel()
        c,d = old.ravel()
        mask = cv2.line(mask, (a,b),(c,d), color[i].tolist(), 2)
        frame = cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,color[i].tolist(),-1)
    img = cv2.add(frame,mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

    # Now update the previous frame and previous points
    old_gray = frame_gray.copy()
    p0 = good_new.reshape(-1,1,2)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

I copied Optical flow sample code from http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html but doesn't work and get this error message I tried to fix but could't

```
line 56, in <module>
cv2.imshow('frame',img)
error: ..\..\..\opencv-2.4.8.1\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:269: 
error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

Answer (score 5):

ERROR here:

```
mask = cv2.line(mask, (a,b),(c,d), color[i].tolist(), 2)
frame = cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,color[i].tolist(),-1)
```

to:

```
#drawing is inplace replacement, line() and circle() will return None!
cv2.line(mask, (a,b),(c,d), color[i].tolist(), 2)
cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,color[i].tolist(),-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Error message is pretty clear: your image can't be shown (line 56, `cv2.imshow('frame', img)`), because it's basically empty - both width and height are zero.

To verify this, just `print img.shape` before showing your image. You then might want to debug your code, step through the lines one by one and figure out where the results are not what you expected.

Comment: Can it be possible opened avi file has no image in it

Comment: Check the retval from cap.read() that you are currently ignoring. If it is False you shouldn't proceed as you reached the end of the movie or something else went wrong.